# What is the difference between [% %] and [%- -%] in Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

What is the difference between `[% %]` and `[%- -%]` in Template Toolkit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-` automatically removes some whitespace from before/after the directive tag.

See [Template::Manual::Syntax](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Manual::Syntax#Chomping-Whitespace):

> You can add `-` or `+` to the immediate start or end of a directive tag to control the whitespace chomping options. See the `PRE_CHOMP` and `POST_CHOMP` options for further details.

See [Template::Manual::Config](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Manual::Config#PRE_CHOMP-POST_CHOMP) for good examples of the effects with and without pre and post chomping.

Comment: And although it is not remotely related to chomping, I like to use [%- -%] because it aligns very nicely with 4-space tab expansion :-)